# Upgraded to 13.04, command not found errors

Tags: 13.04

I'm getting command not found errors on all my scripts I try to run since upgrading. For instance if I navigate to a directory in terminal and then try to execute a script I receive this error. The scripts do have executable permissions.

I did mess around with my path at one point, I don't know if I've messed it up somehow?

```
    # if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin"
fi
```

**Update**
If I run the scripts with "bash" in current dir in the terminal the scripts run i.e. `bash myscript`, however without it I still get command not found error. Would this imply bash is no longer in my path? If so how do I fix this?

Results of `echo $PATH`

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: Do you have it set as executable?

Comment: yup! double checked via terminal and the gui

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 comes with Python 3 by default. If your scripts are written in Python 2 you may need to manually install it. Please check this out for reference https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseNotes#Python_3.3

Comment: @WarrenHill I'm trying to run scripts by navigating to their directory in terminal and executing them by typing their name. This used to work but now the only way I can execute them is by putting bash infront

Comment: @WarrenHill one script has `#!/bin/bash` and another script has `#!/bin/sh`. Running `ls -l` on one of the scripts gives `-rwxrwxrwx`. If you look at my question i've updated with teh results of `echo $PATH`. Am I right in saying `/bin/bash` should be in the results but isn't?

Comment: No **bash** is in `/bin` an and so is **sh**.  You can confirm with `which bash;which sh` and `/bin` is in your path.

Comment: `which bash;which sh 
/bin/bash
/bin/sh` so I guess that's ok

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure I have spotted a mistake.

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin"
fi
```

Does not include the users private bin in the path.  Your path is just `$HOME/bin`

Try this instead

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

You can confirm if this is the problem with `echo $PATH` but as the path you have posted looks OK this tells me that you dont have a `$HOME/bin` directory.

Comment: Thanks have changed PATH to 'PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"' and rebooted. Sadly still getting the same error. The results of 'echo $PATH' are: 
'/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games'